# Como chamar, em Python, uma função cujo nome está armazenado em uma variável?

Tags: python, funções

Tem-se 99 definições de funções distintas:

```
def Fun_1():
...
def Fun_2():
...
def Fun_3():
...
...
...
def Fun_99():
...
```

o valor da variável `x` é obtido aleatoriamente entre 1 e 99:

```
x = aleat(0, 99)
```

A variável `NomeFun` é obtida pela concatenação de `"Fun_"`, o valor de `x` convertido para string e `"()"`:

```
 NomeFun = "Fun_" + str(x) + "()"
```

Como codificar, em Python, a chamada à função cujo nome corresponde ao conteúdo da variável `NomeFun`? Seria algo como:

```
 execute(NomeFun)   ???
```

Answer (score 5):

Pelo fato de existirem 99 funções distintas definidas que serão executadas de forma aleatória, acredito que o problema foi mal desenvolvido e que provavelmente essa não é a melhor solução para o mesmo. Porém, como o problema em si não foi comentado na pergunta, colocarei uma solução para o que foi perguntado.

Todas as referências das funções que existem em um determinado escopo estão disponíveis em um dicionário retornado pela função nativa `locals`. Assim, você pode fazer:

```
functions = locals()
functions["Fun_1"]() # Chama a Fun_1
functions["Fun_9"]() # Chama a Fun_9
...
```

Então, basta alterar o valor de `NomeFun` (e a sintaxe do nome da variável também - vide PEP8):

```
nome_fun = "Fun_" + str(x)
```

E assim chamar a função:

```
functions[nome_fun]()
```

> Veja funcionando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/ybAb4e).

Answer (score 0):

Você pode criar uma função de controle para chamar as demais funções. Exemplo:

```
def execute(nomedafuncao):
    If (nomedafuncao = 'nomedafuncao'):
        funcao
```

Ou:

```
 exec(nomedafuncao)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import random
def f1(x) : return x+11
def f2(x) : return x+22
def f3(x) : return x+33

def a(x):
  return globals()["f%d"% random.randint(1,3)](x)

print(a(100),a(100),a(100))
```

Produzindo (por exemplo)

```
$ python x.py
111 133 111
```